# What does a 9 A battery do to a 3 A motor when using the battery for movement?

Tags: batteries, dc-motor, battery-operated, 12v

I am trying to figure out why my battery keeps discharging so quickly. I have a 12 V, 9 Ah (valve regulated) SLA battery that I use on the bench to test motors. I write a small program, test the source, and then attach the hardware while my board is powered down and the motor is not excited.

All electrical is off and I connect the negative from the driver to the battery negative. I then connect the positive from the driver to the positive battery terminal.

At some point the battery, new batteries also, seem to discharge too rapidly.

My driver can handle 4 A maximum and the motor in question can handle 3 A maximum.

After the SBC has the source written to it, I run the program and find that a fairly new, 12 V, 9 Ah SLA battery whimpers at best against the motor and driver along with the SBC challenges.

I have a couple of battery books, but I have not read exactly about the issue at hand in clear text.

I have my driver set to 2.8 A while the motor has a maximum current limit of 3.0 A.

I have no other circuitry outside of what is located in the driver that handles battery technology, chemical makeup, or any other charging/discharging circuitry. The driver is a [TB6600](https://www.dfrobot.com/product-1547.html).

I think some of the issues I am seeing is that the current is too large for the driver and can't accept enough current as it is overloading it with current.

It is not a deep cycle battery. I see that the driver IC only handles up to 5 A and that is most likely peak current. I may have to downsize batteries or use a PSU with switching characteristics.

Here are some more ideas on the IC and amperage of the driver.

```
Input Current: 0~5 A
Output Current: 0.5-4.0 A
Control Signal: 3.3~24 V
Power (MAX): 160 W
Micro Step: 1, 2/A, 2/B, 4, 8, 16, 32
Temperature: -10～45℃
Humidity: No Condensation
Dimension: 96*56*33 mm/ 3.78*2.2*1.3 inches
Weight: 0.2 kg
Drive IC: TB67S109AFTG
```

Comment: How many ampere-hour capacity does the battery have. How long is the motor driven? *Discharged too rapidly* means what precisely? Data sheet of the battery is probably necessary to link to.

Comment: @Andyaka , sorry. 9Ah/20hr. I will go to find the battery documentation. bbl!

Comment: I found this page online but no mention of docs. on the battery: https://www.amazon.com/Rechargeable-Battery-Computer-BX1300LCD-Back-UPS/dp/B07WRXR223?ref_=ast_sto_dp

Comment: 9Ah 20h means that the battery should support a 450 mA current draw for 20 hours ... higher current draw reduces the runtime, and it is not proportional ... 9A draw will last much less than one hour

Comment: For 3A the battery should last about 2 hours (6 Ah). This is due to the Peukert effect. I have a calculator that illustrates this: http://enginuitysystems.com/EVCalculator.htm Just how long does the battery last at 3A? And what are the actual current and voltage values when running the motor?

Comment: Are the batteries fully charged? What is the date code on the batteries? Old (>2 to 3 years) lead acid batteries will sulfate and have high series resistance unless they were taken care of during storage.

Comment: @qrk ...The batteries were fully charged when I got them in late '22. They are both less than 6 months old.

Comment: @PStechPaul , thank you for the calculator. Testing with batteries is not what I need to be doing. I need a bench PSU that I can plug directly into the outlet, i.e. 115v. I was using 12v @ 0.40A for testing the motor w/ the bench supply.

Comment: @DeFunct When you purchased the batteries and when they were manufactured (the date code stamped on the battery) are two different things. I have seen electronic stores selling 10 year old gel cells.

Comment: I am not sure. I am sorry. There are no date codes on these two batteries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Ah/hr rating on a battery tells you how much power you can draw over what time period. The Amp-hour rating tells you that the product of the current drawn and the time drawn will be 9 Ah, so you could draw for instance 100 mA for 90 hours.

The hour rating tells you how much time you can draw that power over, so in this case you can draw 9 Ah over a period of 20 hours. Doing the math:

$$ \frac{9~\mathrm{Ah}}{20~\mathrm{h}} = 0.45~\mathrm{A}$$

So to get the full 20 hours out of it you would have to limit the current draw to 450 mA.

Comment: At 3 amps it should last about 2 hours due to Peukert effect. http://enginuitysystems.com/EVCalculator.htm

Comment: @PStechPaul Oh. That'll come in handy.